# When do I go through immigration in Europe from Mallorca to Frankfurt to the USA?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

We are traveling home from Mallorca, Spain, to Frankfurt, and then back to the USA. We are considering an affordable flight but the layover is only 50 minutes between landing in Frankfurt and then flying home to the USA. When do we go through immigration there? Would 50 minutes be enough time if so?

Comment: Is this on a single ticket or two separate ones?

Comment: You won't go through customs when you leave the Schengen area, but you will have a passport check by immigration officers.  This will happen in Frankfurt between your arrival gate and your departure gate.  If you're booking those two legs as a single ticket, though, the airline may be able to speed you through.

Answer (score 1):

50 minutes is not likely to be enough even if you're on the same ticket:

- The non-EU passport control lines in Frankfurt are generally busy;
- There are extra document checks and security check for the flights departing to the USA, and the gates on US-bound flights seem to close much earlier ("gate closed 30 minutes before departure");
- Its quite a bit of walk from Schengen area to the gates where US flights depart (AFAIK a different terminal).
- Finally, if you buy two separate tickets on different airlines which are not in alliance, and have luggage, you'd have a bunch of other issues, and definitely not going to make it.

So your chance to miss a flight are pretty high.

Comment: If it's a single ticket, though, the missed flight will cost only time as the travelers will be rebooked.

Comment: @phoog: Time may be a significant cost, however.

Comment: @HenningMakholm of course. People sometimes come here, however, seeking to find out whether some connection where they got a good fare is manageable, and some of those seem not to understand the implications of a missed flight.  Since we already know that price is important to them, we can say that it's that much more likely to be more important to them than time.